# Адаптация строк BootsTrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть 12 блоков по 4 в ряд, как сделать, чтобы при уменьшении экрана последний блок переносился в следующий row, а не создавал новый, т.е. чтобы было по 3 в ряд и последний элемент прыгал в следующий row.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кажется вам нужны флексы или гриды

Comment: не надо вообще делать 2 row тогда и проблемы не будет. сложите все блоки в одну строку

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам @teran в комментарии совершенно справедливо указал на источник проблемы: не нужно делать отдельные row для каждых 4-х блоков, надо сложить все блоки в один row:

```css
[class^="col"] {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
   <div class="block">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```